# How to implement Threading when building buttons with Python/Kivy and separate thread for Buttonpress

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, threadpool, python-multithreading

How to implement threading when building buttons with Kivy in my class
And a separate thread on buttonpress when calling start in :`text="START",size_hint=(SizeW, SizeH), pos_hint={'x': .0, 'y': ButtonY}, on_press=start)`

Or if you have any suggestions how this can be better done or how it should be done i would really appriciate it im really stuck on this

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from filex import start


class Hello(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Hello, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.size = (800, 150)
        Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, 1, 1)

        # Main Buttons
        ButtonY = 0.5
        SizeH = 0.5
        SizeW = 0.33

        
        self.walk_button = Button(background_normal='image4.png',
                                  border=(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                  text="START",size_hint=(SizeW, SizeH), pos_hint={'x': .0, 'y': ButtonY}, on_press=start)
        self.help_button = Button(background_normal='image1.png',
                                  border=(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                  text="Help",  size_hint=(SizeW, SizeH), pos_hint={'x': .67, 'y': 0},on_press=self.update)
        self.go_button = Button(background_normal='image2.png',
                                border=(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                text="Go",      size_hint=(SizeW, SizeH), pos_hint={'x': .335, 'y': 0})

        self.add_widget(self.help_button)
        self.add_widget(self.go_button)
        self.add_widget(self.walk_button)
        
        self.current_text = "Default"


    def update(self,event):
        self.walk_button.text = "Changed to change"

class Example(App):


    def build(self):
        return Hello()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Example();
    x.run();
```

Comment: I think you could improve your question by making smaller amount of code that states the same problem. For instance - make only one button, remove not relevant to the problem lines of code. 
This way it will be easier to help and for others to relate to your problem and find answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use threading by calling:

```
threading.Thread(target=self.update).start()
```

This is a good idea when your button is starting a method that takes a significant time to run. (Significant is any length of time that you do not want your GUI blocked). However, anything that modifies the GUI must be done on the main thread,
so the `update()` method in your question is not a candidate for running in a separate thread. If you have a long running method that also needs to modify the GUI, then run it in a separate thread, but call another method that only does the GUI modifications using:

```
Clock.schedule_once()
```